# Run published web (C# MVC) from CMD console

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have the publish of my web project and I want to run from CMD console

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could use appcmd to achieve your requirement.

You could use CMD cosnole to run the appcmd command to start the IIS's MVC application or stop the IIS's MVC application.

More details, you could refer to below command and article:

```
 appcmd stop site /site.name: contoso 
 appcmd start site /site.name: contoso
```

Article:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe